# Optimization for Kusto query

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

How to optimize the KQL parsing strings to get quick output, less than 10 seconds;

*Example*:
**where message contains "this is the error code following this format –"**

should we change it to hex to see if this parses quickly :
**where message contains "7468697320697320746865206572726f7220636f646520666f6c6c6f77696e67207468697320666f726d61742096"``**

Comment: Fixed your ALL CAPS in the title.

Answer (score 2):

From the documentation ([String Operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/datatypes-string-operators)):

> "Kusto builds a term index consisting of all terms that are three characters or more, and this index is used by string operators such as has,!has, and so on. **If the query looks for a term that is smaller than three characters, or uses a ***contains*** operator, then the query will revert to scanning the values in the column**. Scanning is much slower than looking up the term in the term index."

Instead of `contains` use one of the `has[...]` operators described in the documentation, preferably a case-sensitive one (`has_cs`, `hasprefix_cs`, `hassuffix_cs` etc.).

Search for fewer terms as possible, e.g., if `... has_cs "ErrorCode"` is enough to filter out the records you need, prefer it over searches like `... has "this is the ErrorCode following this format"`

P.S.
I've been doing similar searches, over milliards of records, on my own development ADX cluster, in sub-seconds.

Comment: See update ("Search for fewer terms as possible...)